# IndexError: list index out of range for making a variable structure library

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, scipy

Hi I am trying to build a model structure library with different combinations. Structure library is based on 5 variables for which I need five models. i-e modelsOne, modelsTwo and so on upto five. For simplicity I am pasting the code in bunches which is same for all five models. It has very little change in it. 
When I execute the code I get the following error

> modelOne = modelsOne[temp1]
>
> **IndexError: list index out of range**

```
def ModelsProduct(modelsOne, modelsTwo, modelsThree, modelsFour,modelsFive):


    modelsStepOne = list(product("+-",repeat = 4))
    modelsStepThree = [('a','a'),('a','b'),('a','c'),('a','d'),('a','e'),('b','b'),('b','c'),('b','d'),('b','e'),('c','c'),('c','d'),('c','e')]
    modelsStepFour = [('d','d'),('d','e')]
    modelsStepFive = [('e','e')]



    #produce modelsOne
    modelsStepTwo = [('d',),('e',)]
    for one in modelsStepOne:
        for two in modelsStepTwo:
            for three in modelsStepThree:
                for four in modelsStepFour:
                    for five in modelsStepFive:
                        modelsOne.append(one+two+three+four+five)

    #produce modelsTwo
    modelsStepTwo = [('c',),('d',)]
    for one in modelsStepOne:
        for two in modelsStepTwo:
            .
            .
            .
   return modelsOne, modelsTwo, modelsThree, modelsFour, modelsFive


modelsOne, modelsTwo,modelsThree, modelsFour,modelsFive = ModelsProduct(modelsOne, modelsTwo, modelsThree, modelsFour, modelsFive)

VarList = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
initial_condi = [10, 15, 5,4,5]

dictVar = {'a':0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e':4}
ops = { "+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub }
t_range = arange(0.0,60.0,1.0)


def odeFunc(Y, t, x,dictVar):

    if x[-5] == 3072:
        temp1 = 3071
    else:
        temp1 = int(x[-5])

    if x[-4] == 3072:
        temp2 = 3071
    else:
        temp2 = int(x[-4])


    if x[-3] == 3072:
        temp3 = 3071
    else:
        temp3 = int(x[-3])

    if x[-2] == 3072:
        temp4 = 3071
    else:
        temp4 = int(x[-2])

    if x[-1] == 3072:
        temp5 = 3071
    else:
        temp5 = int(x[-1])

    modelOne = modelsOne[temp1]
    modelTwo = modelsTwo[temp2]
    modelThree = modelsThree[temp3]
    modelFour = modelsFour[temp4]
    modelFive = modelsFive[temp5]
    return GenModel(Y, x, modelOne,modelTwo,modelThree,modelFour,modelFive, dictVar)

def GenModel(Y,x,modelOne,modelTwo,modelThree,modelFour,modelFive, dictVar):
    dydt = zeros_like(Y)

    dydt[0] = ops[modelOne[0]](dydt[0],x[0]*Y[0])#  k1 x1
    dydt[0] = ops[modelOne[1]](dydt[0],x[1]*Y[dictVar[modelOne[-5]]])# k2 x2
    dydt[0] = ops[modelOne[2]](dydt[0],x[2]*Y[dictVar[modelOne[-4]]])# k3 x3
    dydt[0] = ops[modelOne[3]](dydt[0],x[3]*Y[dictVar[modelOne[-3]]])# k4 x4
    dydt[0] = ops[modelOne[4]](dydt[0],x[4]*Y[dictVar[modelOne[-2]]]*Y[dictVar[modelOne[-1]]])#k5 x5 x6
    dydt[0] = ops[modelOne[5]](dydt[0],x[5])# k6

    dydt[1] = ops[modelTwo[0]](dydt[1],x[6]*Y[0])
    dydt[1] = ops[modelTwo[1]](dydt[1],x[7]*Y[dictVar[modelTwo[-5]]])
    dydt[1] = ops[modelTwo[2]](dydt[1],x[8]*Y[dictVar[modelTwo[-4]]])
    dydt[1] = ops[modelTwo[3]](dydt[1],x[9]*Y[dictVar[modelTwo[-3]]])
    dydt[1] = ops[modelTwo[4]](dydt[1],x[10]*Y[dictVar[modelTwo[-2]]]*Y[dictVar[modelTwo[-1]]])
    dydt[1] = ops[modelTwo[5]](dydt[1],x[11])
.
.
.
.   return dydt
```

Comment: You are trying to take `modelsOne[3071]`. How many elements does `modelsOne` have?

Comment: Range of total structure for each model is 3072.

Comment: If you are trying to fetch the last element I suggest using `modelsOne[-1]`

Comment: Yes. Actually it is build on the this model :  
##  My model k1x1 k2x2  k3x3  k4x4 k5x5x6  k6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the length of the following list is 16

```
list(product("+-",repeat = 4))
```

but, looks like the temp1 is 
`temp1 = 3071`

so, when accesing 
`modelOne = modelsOne[temp1]`
so, this might be causing the error

Comment: With value 5 it was giving the same error. But once I change it to 6. It gives me the RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply. Should I continue with it ?

Comment: can you tell me ,what is it you are trying to achieve, so that i can give you an overall solution

Comment: Thank you brother. It works. My overall model combinations is 29 for which  "4" and "5" is not worthy. Giving the Runtime Warning because I am trying to optimize Differential Equations which involve high computation and take 10 hours or more for execution of a program.